# Selenium grid - limit of the nodes on the same machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

In Selenium Grid, is there any limit of nodes on the same machine.

I have 500 test suites to run in parallel, and considering to setup a hub with 25 nodes each with `MaxSessions` of 20 Firefox browsers in the same machine or should I run virtual machines with Linux platform and register my nodes there to the hub?

Thank you for your advises.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can limit the number of nodes with selenium grid

you can do something like this:

1. Start Hub with max number of session (use -maxSession 500)
2. Start node with limited number browsers. Since you want 25 nodes, with 20 firefox browser. It would look like something like this (assuming you are using java):

   ```
   Java -jar %SELENIUM_GRID_VERSION% -role node -hub  %HUB_URL%  -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=20,platform=LINUX
   ```

This will insure that only 20 firefox browser will open on node1.

I would advice you to use Virtual Machines to run your test suite. Especially since you want run your test suites parallel. Running on same machine will use up a lot of your computer resources and the nodes might not register with hub or give you an error like "Unable to bind to locking port XXXX within 45000 ms", causing your test to fail.